# Possible to rank a user or SE site based on language "grade" level?

Tags: discussion, grammar

Jeff Atwood wrote about how Stack Exchange is a clever way [to trick programmers](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html) into becoming better writers.

This sparked some curiosity.

1. Is there a way to see if my writing has improved over time?
2. How do the various Stack Exchange sites compare to each other?
3. Are there certain trends, such as users over xxx rep having better writing skills than those with x?

Comment: I'm guessing the writing on English.SE would be pretty decent...

Comment: @AdamRackis: Actually, I've seen some pretty terrible questions on there. (The answers tend to be better, of course.)

Comment: As a rough guide, have a look at the early versions of your older posts, the worse they look now, the more you have improved since then

Comment: @BrianReichle I was thinking more along the lines of an automated scanner that will compare the objects I listed.  I like idea of an impartial scanner that says what post is of a reading level equal to a trash mag or that of the WSJ or higher..

Comment: @makerofthings7 - I'm not sure scanning posts to analyze writing quality is a Turing complete problem

Comment: Look at the edits made to your posts. If you really want, write a SEDE query to check the average number of body edits not made by you over various periods of time.